# How to draw a shape that keeps constant shape and size when resizing the window?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

From what I understand, OpenGL always accepts coordinates from -1.0 to 1.0. When the viewport changes, when a window is resized, the distances between points are not preserved.
For example, when the viewport width is 400, the distance between points (0.5,0.0) and (-0.5,0.0) is 200, and when the width is 600, it is 300.

I need to draw a shape (of a scrollbar or something similar), that shouldn't change its width, when the window is resized. I've seen on other posts, that people calculate the floating point coordinates using the window width, but that introduces the problem of floating point accuracy, which can lead to the shape being nearly constant size, but sometimes not exactly.

How to make a shape, that will stay exactly the same width, no matter the width of the window?

The code I'm running is really just a simple triangle appearing on the screen that can be resized. The code is nonetheless a bit long.

```
#include <iostream>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>



const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

void onSize (GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport (0,0,width, height);
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "hello", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, onSize);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "error with vertex shader compilation\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "error with fragment shader compilation\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "error with linking program\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Left  
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right 
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // Top   
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

    glBindVertexArray(0); 

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

So how do I make it so that this triangle has constant width and height regardless of resizing the window?

Comment: show us what you have.

Comment: You need to use an orthographic projection matrix.

Comment: *"which can lead to the shape being nearly constant size, but sometimes not exactly."* - Have you tried it out (to make sure it is a problem at all)?

Comment: @Meowmere the floating problems are really hard to reproduce, but nonetheless this approach is bound to have some off by one problems connected to rounding, and it really doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: "Meowmere the floating problems are really hard to reproduce, but nonetheless this approach is bound to have some off by one problems connected to rounding, and it really doesn't seem like the best solution." That is just not how it works at all. First of all, floating point issues are easy to reproduce since floating pint logic is completely deterministic, there is no magic invloved. Second, GPU rasterization is based on fixed point math, the coordis will be snapped in to some subpixel grid, so slight inaccuracies do not matter at all.

Comment: Third, you are taliking about pixel precision in NDC space, together with my first and second point, if you use the _right_ math, there are no precision issues at all, and no rounding errors which would lead to a wrong result. You'll have an huge _excess_ of precision in standard single precision float math to get pixel-precision for all of the supported viewport sizes of today's GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is related to the phrase in your question: *"I need to draw a shape [...], that shouldn't change its width, when the window is resized."*

You have to use [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection).

Add a [Uniform variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) of type `mat4` to the vertex shader and multiply the vertex coordinate with the matrix uniform:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 u_projection;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projection * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Define the vertices in pixel unit:

```cpp
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -100.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f, // Left  
     100.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f, // Right 
     100.0f,  100.0f, 0.0f  // Top   
};
```

Get the current width and height of the viewport and set the matrix using [`glm::ortho`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#gae5b6b40ed882cd56cd7cb97701909c06):

```cpp
GLint proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_projection");

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    int width, height;
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);

    // [...]

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(
        -width/2.0f, width/2.0f, -height/2.0f, height/2.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

    // [...]
}
```